# Check if soap connection working

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

Quick one,
How would you go about checking if your connection to a soap server is actually connecting?

I have this code:

```
$m_wsdl = "https://m2mconnect.orange.co.uk/orange-soap/services/MessageServiceByCountry?wsdl";
    try {
        $client = new SoapClient($m_wsdl);

        $this->m_messages = $client->peekMessages('','',10,"");
    } catch (Exception $e) {

        echo "Exception: \n" . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    }

    $this->do_parse_xml();
```

Obviously my username and password are in the peekmessages field where they should be, and they are both correct i am 100%.

For some reason its not returning any data at all and i dont know how to check to see if the connection is actually working??

Im getting no exceptions being echo'd

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

Use `isSoapFault()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-soap-fault.php

Also, the `peekMessages` method would probably return `false` or a `SoapFault`.

You can also set `Exceptions` to true on the `SoapClient`

Comment: Why will the peekMessages return a fault or false? Thanks

Comment: Many PHP functions have a mixed return type. That way you can do something like `if($client->$peekMessages) { blah blah blah }`.